# How can I pass a template to a directive in an attribute?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to pass a template to a directive like this:

```
<my-directive template="/templates/my-directive-template.html"></my-directive>
```

If no template is provided then the standard template is used.
How can I achieve this?

*Or shouldn't I do this? I just want to reuse a directive, but want to give it different appearances each time.*

Here's the directive... but I'm stuck on how to move forward.

```
app.directive('my-directive', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      template: '=template'
    },
    template: 'standard-template.html'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`templateUrl` can be a function, that gets the element and its attributes as arguments. So you can do the following:

```
app.directive('my-directive', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {
                return attrs.template || 'standard-template.html';
              }
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me, it is showing the path in the rendered html

Comment: @JustGoscha Sorry, it should be `templateUrl`, of course. Updated the answer.

Comment: ah yes, nice thanks, this was quick. I like this answer more because it keeps the same scope, so my `$watch`ers still work :)

Comment: Ok, now I have the problem, that the 'standard-template.html' is parsed by Angular, but the other one is not ... so everywhere are `{{}}` etc. :/

Comment: @JustGoscha I guess there's an error in some JavaScript code. Do you see anything in the console?

Comment: ...ah yes my bad, I forgot to remove the `template: '=template'` in the scope of the directive,... then it couldn't parse the attribute when I did it like `template="template.html", then I panicked... and wrote a comment. ^^

Answer (score 2):

You could use ng-include. So as an example

```
app.directive('my-directive', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      template: '=?'
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="directiveTemplate"></div>',
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.directiveTemplate = scope.template || '/path/to/default.tpl.html';
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: or you could incorporate some of the functionality of `ng-include` into your directive (although reusing it makes more sense). I made an experiment [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/N6TD7Jrh6jew7gxd5jD4?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks, this works, but it creates a child scope so I couldn't use the watchers that I set up...